# Is there any way to define a default itemrenderer for flex halo datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer

While this sounds like an easy task, I wasn't able to find a solution.
I have a DataGrid with no defined columns but with an ItemRenderer (on the DataGrid itself).
I want the datagrid to use this ItemRenderer when data is populated into it.

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dataGrid" height="100%" width="100%" itemRenderer="my.renderer" />
```

By looking at the DataGrid code, it looks like this should only on a predefined columns.
The only workaround I found was to assign the itemRenderer after I populate the dataProvider (which creates the column automatically)

Answer (score 1):

An ItemRenderer is defined on a column; not on the DataGrid, so I would expect your code to throw a compiler error.

The itemRenderer is a property, so it cannot be set with CSS on the DataGridColumn.

However, the MX DataGrid does have a style name defaultDataGridItemRenderer which should pass onto the GridColumns.  You should be able to set that in CSS and use that to define the default itemRenderer for each column.

When you finally have a dataProvider; you could also manually create the columns in ActionScript and set the itemRenderer on each column that way.

My original suggestion, before discovering the defaultDataGridItemRenderer style was to say that could extend the DataGridColumn class to set a default itemRenderer value.  However, in the code sample you provided you are not manually defining columns; so you would also have to extend the DataGrid in order to use your custom column class.

Comment: thanks for the answer but ItemRenderer can be defined on the DataGrid itself (it works) and I haven't tried to set it with CSS (did I say CSS?)

Comment: @ofir itemRenderer is not a documented property on the MX DataGrid: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html so I have no idea why that works.

Comment: I think the `defaultDataGridItemRenderer` is what you need; and updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

the itemRenderer property is ListBase(DataGrid extend ListBase)

if you set DataGrid.itemRenderer="mx.controls.TextInput" and column you havn't set value, then   the DataGrid will use TextInput to create item renderer and header renderer.

this is source code in DataGrid

```
public function createColumnItemRenderer(c:DataGridColumn, forHeader:Boolean, data:Object):IListItemRenderer
{
    var factory:IFactory;

    // get the factory for the data
    factory = c.getItemRendererFactory(forHeader, data);
    if (!factory)
    {
        if (!data)
            factory = nullItemRenderer;
        if (!factory)
            factory = itemRenderer;
    }
```